# Two variables in for loop in bash

Tags: bash

```
for file in /root/*
do
    if [ "$file" != "/root/00" ] && [ "$file" != "/root/01" ]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

in this code, as you see i try to get the files in the `/root` folder the output should be like this:

```
/root/02
/root/03
/root/04
/root/05
etc....
```

then i will use the output with `commands`

i have txt file, let's say the content like this:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

i need read the `txt file` lines with the output from the code above in the same for loop, for example in the code `echo $file` i need change it to `echo $file $line` `$line` = the lines in the `txt file`

i found someone asked for something like my question and other in `stackoverflow`: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/75414-sh-two-variables-loop.html

but all these, will not help me, because there are specific thing i need it!

what is the problem with their codes?

the problem is the out put will be like this:

**the out put + the txt file**

```
/root/02 first line
/root/03 second line
/root/04 third line
/root/05
/root/06
```

i need if the output lines more than the lines in the `txt file` return to the first line in the `txt file` for example:

```
/root/02 first line
/root/03 second line
/root/04 third line
/root/05 first line
/root/06 second line
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the lines of the file in an array. Then you can index the array with wraparound.

```
readarray -t lines < filename.txt
i=0
for file in /root/*
do
    if [ "$file" != "/root/00" ] && [ "$file" != "/root/01" ]
    then
        printf "%s %s\n" "$file" "${lines[$i]}"
        i=$(((i + 1) % "${#lines[@]}")) # increment i and wrap around to 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: You probably want `readarray -t ...`. For some reason, the default is to include each line's trailing newline in the array entries; `-t` tells it not to do this.